# Running installer within docker file without user interaction

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, eclipse-che

I've been trying to have a docker file setup where it can install a specific ODBC driver I need in an application. 
I use the following commands:

1. RUN cd /tmp/./client1201/
2. RUN ./setup

and it runs the installer without any problem. The issue is that It requires user input in order to proceed with some steps.

Is there any way I can make this silent? If so, is this some docker specific feature? Or it actually requires some sort of support from the installer itself in order to achieve this?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: A driver install that requires user input sounds kind of broken :/. Nevertheless, this may be a task for `expect`.

Comment: Nothing to do with Docker per se, but like @OliverCharlesworth says, something that requires manual input is horribly bad.

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is a Sybase ODBC driver required in the application. Maybe I have a wrong approach to the problem. How would you approach the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
RUN echo "yes" | ./script.sh
```

This may work for you.